# Function produces output alphabetically, order by average score instead

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

This function shows the average score for each person in database from 3 most recent results. The output is ordered by name, how can I get it to order by average, highest to lowest.

```
def averagescore():
    allnames = []
    itr = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM "+group+" GROUP BY name;").fetchall()#lists names in database
    for x in itr:
        if x not in allnames:
            allnames.append(x[0])
        else:
            False
    allnames.sort()
    avg = 0
    number = 0

    for name in allnames:
        cursor.execute("SELECT total FROM "+group+" WHERE (\""+name+"\") = NAME ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 3;")#3 most recent scores
        scores =(cursor.fetchall())     

        scores = [i[0] for i in scores]        
        avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)
        print(name,"'s average is: ",avg,". From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were: ",scores,)
        avg = 0
```

The output is:

```
AZ 's average is:  0.0 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0]
ED 's average is:  0.6666666666666666 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0, 1, 1]
JAKE 's average is:  2.0 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0, 4]
SAM 's average is:  0.0 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0]
ZAC 's average is:  0.0 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0]
```

I would like it to be:

```
JAKE 's average is:  2.0 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0, 4]
ED 's average is:  0.6666666666666666 . From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were:  [0, 1, 1]
```

ETC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

(please see here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting )

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# datastruct
# name, avg, [scores]

datastruct = [
    ['AZ', 0.0, [0]],
    ['ED', 0.6666666666666666, [0, 1, 1]],
    ['JAKE', 2.0, [0, 4]],
    ['SAM', 0.0, [0]],
    ['ZAC', 0.0, [0]]
]

print('before')
for item in datastruct:
    print(item)

print('after')
for item in sorted(datastruct, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True):
    print("{}'s avg is: {}. From (up to 3) most recent scores which were: {}".format(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of combined records from the two sql queries and then sort them by average as answered by @davejagoda.

In relation to your needs, the first for loop, I would use a set for `allnames` then convert that into a sorted list. After that I would build a list of `records` which is just `[{'name': 'foo'}, {'name': 'bar'}, ...]`. Then I would do the second DB query using each of these names as you did and update that record in-place with `avg` and `scores`.

After that is achieved, I would then sort records `records` list by `avg` in descending order and print out the results.

For this, your code would look like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# ... your other code goes here

def averagescore():
    names_sql = "SELECT name FROM {0} GROUP BY name;".format(group)
    # lists names in database
    itr = cursor.execute(names_sql)
    allnames = sorted(list({x[0] for x in itr}))

    records = [{'name': name} for name in allnames]

    scores_sql = """
        SELECT total
          FROM {0}
         WHERE ("{1}") = NAME
      ORDER BY DATE DESC
         LIMIT 3;
    """

    for record in records:
        name = record['name']
        # 3 most recent scores
        itr = cursor.execute(scores_sql.format(group, name))
        scores = [i[0] for i in itr]
        avg = sum(scores) / len(scores)
        record.update({'avg': avg, 'scores': scores})

    tally.sort(key=itemgetter('avg'), reverse=True)

    for record in records:
        print(
            record['name'],
            "'s average is: ",
            record['avg'],
            ". From (up to) 3 most recent scores which were: ",
            record['scores']
        )
```